# Beginner C++ hw. Function doesnt seem to work

Tags: c++, class, function

I've been working on this assignment that wants me to make a class that outputs a month and day when the user inputs a number from 1 - 365 . I'm not getting any errors but I can't seem to get any output from my `print()` function. Any help would be appreciated. :]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class DayOfYear
{
    public:
        DayOfYear(){};
        DayOfYear(int);
        ~DayOfYear(){};
        void print();

    private:
    int day;

};

int main()
{
    int numInput;
    cout << "\n\n\tPlease enter a day number between 1 and 365.\n\t";
    cin >> numInput;
    while ((numInput < 1) || (numInput > 365))
    {
        cout << "\n\tError* Please enter a number between 1 and 365.\n\t";
        cin >> numInput;
    };

    DayOfYear day1(numInput);
    //cout << "\n\n\tThat day is ";
    day1.print();
    cout << " ";

    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}    


DayOfYear::DayOfYear(int numInput)
{
    numInput = day;
}

void DayOfYear::print()
{
    if (day>0 && day<=31)
    {
        cout << "January " << day;
    };
    if (day>31 && day<=59)
    {
        cout << "February " << (day-31);
    };
    if (day>59 && day<=90)
    {
        cout << "March " << (day-59);
    };
    if (day>90 && day<=120)
    {
        cout << "April " << (day-90);
    };
    if (day>120 && day<=151)
    {
        cout << "May " << (day-120);
    };
    if (day>151 && day<=181)
    {
        cout << "June " << (day-151);
    };
    if (day>181 && day<=212)
    {
        cout << "July " << (day-181);
    };
    if (day>212 && day<=243)
    {
        cout << "August " << (day-212);
    };
    if (day>243 && day<=273)
    {
        cout << "September " << (day-243);
    };
    if (day>273 && day<=304)
    {
        cout << "October " << (day-273);
    };
    if (day>304 && day<=334)
    {
        cout << "November " << (day-304);
    };
    if (day>334 && day<=365)
    {
        cout << "December " << (day-334);
    };
}
```

Comment: Produce an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). That act will probably fix it.

Comment: @chris in this case the description is pretty concise and an example won't add much.

Comment: @icepack, I still think it would have a good chance at the OP being able to figure it out for themself. For example, the problem persists (hopefully, due to the UB) when the entire print function just prints the day. There's most of the code gone.

Comment: This kind of error could have been picked by your compiler. Find a way to activate the warnings on your compiler, and read them.

Comment: Thank you everyone :] , especially @Jcl (first answer). I will definitely look into and initialization list, I don't really have any idea what one it but I'm going to have to learn about it eventually. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
DayOfYear::DayOfYear(int numInput)
{
    numInput = day;
}
```

It should be

```
    day = numInput;
```

Otherwise `day` is undefined, which won't produce an output in `print`

Comment: Otherwise, it's undefined behaviour, not 0.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor is wrong.

It should be :

```
DayOfYear::DayOfYear(int numInput){
    day = numInput;
}
```

Also you could use an initialization list bringing your code to this shape:

```
DayOfYear::DayOfYear(int numInput): day(numInput) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DayOfYear::DayOfYear(int numInput)
{
    numInput = day;
}
```

should be

```
DayOfYear::DayOfYear(int numInput)
{
    day = numInput;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`DayOfYear::DayOfYear(int numInput)`
`{`
   `numInput = day;`
`}`

Problem is that in definition of constructor, you are assigning value of day to numInput. So it won't make any impact on the value of object's day field.

Solution: `DayOfYear::DayOfYear(int numInput)`
`{`
   `day = numInput;`
`}`

now this statement means, assign value of numInput to day.

Answer (score 1):

You have a false assignment

```
DayOfYear::DayOfYear(int numInput)
{
  numInput = day; //
}
```

What you need is

```
DayOfYear::DayOfYear(int numInput)
  : day(numInput)
{}
```

Use [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) instead of assignment!

Answer (score 1):

Change your declaration

```
DayOfYear::DayOfYear(int numInput)
{
    day=numInput;
}
```

Instead of using the above, You can also pass numInput values to print function and You can check your condition directly.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor uses

```
numInput = day;
```

where it should be:

```
day = numInput;
```

Which, of course, has already been pointed out. Something that I *haven't* seen pointed out is that you could have coded the DayOfYear::print function to use chained if...else if...else statements, rather than a bunch of independent if clauses. That would make it easier to check for error conditions, and hence might help with debugging.

For instance, if you had something like the following:

```
void DayOfYear::print()
{
    if (day>0 && day<=31)
    {
        cout << "January " << day;
    }
    else if (day>31 && day<=59)
    {
        cout << "February " << (day-31);
    }
    /* bunch more here else ifs here */
    else
    {
        cout << "That's not a date! Value of 'day' is " << day;
    }
}
```

Then it may have been easier to see why, exactly, things were going wrong (in this case: crazy values, hence probably something that's uninitialized).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your constructor. You print your result based on the value of the variable `day` . But you are not assigning any value to this variable , so you get some garbage value and don't get the right answer. Just change this code portion

```
    DayOfYear::DayOfYear(int numInput)
    {
        numInput = day;
    }
to this:

    DayOfYear::DayOfYear(int numInput)
    {
        day = numInput;
    }
```

and in your print function I will suggest to use `else if` instead of so many `if`. Here I can give an example:

```
    if (day>0 && day<=31)
    {
        cout << "January " << day;
    }
    else if (day>31 && day<=59)
    {
        cout << "February " << (day-31);
    }
    else if (day>59 && day<=90)
    {
        cout << "March " << (day-59);
    }
    //and so on
```

It is preferable to use this because if you use `else if` when you get an true value it will not check the following 'else if' statements. But it in your code , after getting a true value , it will unnecessarily check the following `if` statements.